# user login using email instead of username. issue: passing email but its checking username

Tags: html, django, forms, django-views, django-templates

I am unable to login with email but I am able to do it with username. How do I login with email instead of username.
This is my html page : I tried to pass email instead of username but unable to login
[image]

This is my views.py file: When i try to authenticate by change username to email, it is printing "invalid login details supplied!"
[image]
This is forms.py:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Follow this steps:**

In **dj/views.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
import re
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class UsernameOrEmailBackend(ModelBackend):

    def authenticate(self,request, username=None, password=None,**kwargs):
        if '@' in username:        # Apply your custom validation like '.' and custom domain...
            kwargs = {'email': username}
        elif re.search("^0?[5-9]{1}\d{9}$",username):   #optional
            kwargs = {'phone_no':username}    
        else:
            kwargs = {'username': username}   
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(**kwargs)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

in **settings.py:**

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS =['dj.views.UsernameOrEmailBackend',     
                          'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
                         ]
```